# accessors and update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have a model with a location attribute, it's a array of two elements; latitude and longitude. I define the accessors for the location like this

```
class Address
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    include Mongoid::Spacial::Document

    field :location,        :type => Array,    spacial: {lat: :latitude, lng: :longitude, return_array: true }


    #accessors for location


    def latitude
        location[0]
    end

    def latitude=( lat )
        location[0] = latitude
    end

    def longitude
        location[1]
    end

    def longitude=( lng )
        location[1] = lng
    end
    attr_accessible :location, :latitude, :longitude

end
```

here is the controller code

```
def create
        @address = Address.new(params[:address])
        if @address.save
            redirect_to :action => 'index'
        else
            render :action => 'new'
        end
    end

    def update
        @address = Address.find(params[:id])

        if @address.update_attributes(params[:address])
            redirect_to :action => 'index'
        else
            render :action => 'edit'
        end

    end
```

and at the view level

```
<%= f.hidden_field :latitude%>
<%= f.hidden_field :longitude%>
```

these hidden field are manipulated via js, and that is ok. I saw it view developers tools

Here are the parameters the controller receives

```
"address"=>{"latitude"=>"-38.0112418", "longitude"=>"-57.53713060000001", "city_id"=>"504caba825ef893715000001", "street"=>"alte. brown", "number"=>"1234", "phone"=>"223 4568965"}, "commit"=>"Guardar", "id"=>"504cacc825ef893715000006"}
```

Note that the latitude and longitude parameters changed and thats ok, but this change it's not saved to the mongodb

So, The values for latitude and longitude are not saved. Is there any instruction my code is missing?

Thanks in advance.

--- edit ---

here are the working accessors

```
    def latitude
        location[0]
    end

    def latitude=( lat )
        self.location = [lat,self.location[1]]
    end

    def longitude
        location[1]
    end

    def longitude=( lng )
        self.location = [self.location[0], lng]
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to set a field of your database, use `self` always safer and it's a good habit.

Second thing, you have to use the argument you pass to the setter.

Resulting code:

```
def latitude
  location[0]
end

def latitude=( lat )
  self.location[0] = lat
end

def longitude
  location[1]
end

def longitude=( lng )
  self.location[1] = lng
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's true in this case - `location[0]=foo` isn't ambiguous in the way that `location=foo` is

Comment: @FrederickCheung: you're right, just tried. Now it's obvious, would have raised exception otherwise. Still, it's a good habit to use `self` in this case, and I think the issue was due to improper setter methods

Comment: Thanks. I see the error. But beside the misspell, i've solve the problem with your help and self.location = [lat,self.location[1]]. I don't see why i need to create a new array. Thanks!